# How can I change the overlay color in fancyBox v2

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

In fancyBox version 1 there was the `overlayColor` parameter, but in version 2 it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Editing the CSS doesn't work because it gets over-written by the JavaScript in the plugin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fancybox v2.x API option are new and are not compatible with previous versions so `overlayColor` has been replaced by the `helpers` => `overlay` => `css` => `background-color` option.

You **don't have to mess** with the original (js or css) files either as suggested by @Sparky672 (that is a bad <strike>practice</strike> idea). You can set that option in your custom script ... so having this html for instance:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg">open fancybox with a red overlay</a>
```

use a custom script like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers : { 
   overlay: {
    opacity: 0.8, // or the opacity you want 
    css: {'background-color': '#ff0000'} // or your preferred hex color value
   } // overlay 
  } // helpers
}); // fancybox
```

Comment: Yours is clearly the better answer, however, editing the CSS or JS cannot be summarily called _"a bad practice"_; that's just unfairly inaccurate. For this particular case, the [poorly documented](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) `helpers` parameter, obviously, is preferred. However, for plugins without the availability of a desired parameter, such a customization is impossible without editing the CSS and/or JavaScript. After all, editing existing code is not such a long stretch from simply writing your own plugin.

Comment: OK, I took it back ... and yes, you are right: unfortunately some options of this great plugin are poorly documented.

Comment: that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @JFK, It does not set the `opacity`.

Comment: @shweta : unfortunately this answer is outdated because it was for fancybox v2.0.x. Things have changed since v2.1.x. For an updated information on the same topic,  check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.1

Comment: This does not work anymore. Fancybox has been updated.

Comment: @user734063 your are correct, this answer is more than 2 years old and valid for versions previous to 2.1.x. For an updated answer check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15096928/1055987 (as I previously commented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740443/how-can-i-change-the-overlay-color-in-fancybox-v2/9743651?noredirect=1#comment26942352_9743651) a year ago)

Answer (score 5):

Firefox (and IE 9) don't like setting an overlay opacity.
Chrome is fine with it but in Firefox + IE9 the opacity is applied to the popup itself. They seem to do layering differently for the overlay and contents.

Tested in *[Fancybox 2.1.4](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)*

```
 helpers:
 {
       overlay:
       {
              css: { 'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)' }
       }
 }
```

If you set an RGBA value instead then it will work. You have to use `background` and not `background-color` to override the default css.

Note that the plugin itself uses a semi-transparent PNG for the overlay. This is fine, but has two downsites. Firstly it has to load and unless you pre-load it the fade-in effect can be a little stuttered the first time you open a popup. Second most browsers suppress requests after you've submitted a form - so unless you pre-load the PNG then there'll be no overlay at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can target the `style` tag that is applied to the `#fancybox-overlay` div by using an attribute selector, like so:

**CSS**

```
#fancybox-overlay[style] {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### From [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api) v1.3:

**Overlay Options Defaults**:

- overlayOpacity: 0.3
- overlayColor: #666

**Working Example**:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    overlayOpacity  : 0.8, // Set opacity to 0.8
    overlayColor    : "#000000" // Set color to Black
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Fancybox 3 you are supposed to change overlay with CSS. See this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1370#issuecomment-293915892).

This is how you can do it:

```css
.fancybox-is-open {
 .fancybox-bg {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Options built into fancyBox v1 will not work if they're not built into fancyBox2.  And according [to the fancyBox v2 documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs), there's no such `overlayColor` option.

My suggestion is to try and change the `background` color within the `jquery.fancybox.css` file for `#fancybox-overlay`.

```
#fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1001;
    background: #000;  /* <<-- this one  */
}
```

---

**EDIT based on comments:**

The technically correct answer is:  *you can't set the `overlayColor` option because the new version will not accept that obsolete parameter.*

However, if you're willing to edit the plugin, this should do it...

around line `1308` of `jquery.fancybox.js` you'll see the overlay options.

```
opts = $.extend(true, {
    speedIn : 'fast',
    closeClick : true,
    opacity : 1,
    css : {
        background: 'black'  //  <-- this one
    }
}, opts);

this.overlay = $('<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>').css(opts.css).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: I tried the css method already. It's not working because it's overridden by javascript :|

Comment: I was looking for some options / extension or css to achieve that. I don't wanna hack the js file

Answer (score 0):

The css #fancybox-overlay seems not working for me (fb2), i use .fancybox-skin works perfectly.

```
.fancybox-skin{
background-color:#121212!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In last version the helper need the parent parameter, like this:

```
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open({parent: $('body')});
```

Answer (score 0):

use css for bg:

```
#fancy_bg
{
    background-color:000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, this works. If you'd like no background color, set it to none;

```
.fancybox-bg {
   background-color: #FF0004;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS for **fancybox v3.x**

```
<style>
    .fancybox-is-open .fancybox-bg {
        opacity: 1;
        background: #888;
    }
</style>
```