# Smart way to make/improve image preview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

This question will be a little longer and I am sorry for that :)
I search for the best solution for a few days to make image gallery in asp mvc and JQuery.
The main issue is displaying image when user click on thumb.
I want to make whole browser view black and image in the center (width/height 100%).
I have made something and it works. But have a few issues that I didn't make to fix.
Here how I did it:
I have ImagesController and Index view, that view contains image thumbs. ImageID I store in name attribute of image tag. When user click on thumb image I call this jquery function:

```
$('.imageThumb').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Images/Show")',
        data: "imgId=" + $(this)[0].name,
        success: function (d) {
            $(document.body).append(d);
            $(document.body).css("overflow", "hidden");
        }
    })
});
```

This Show view is the fullscreen browser view that display selected image:

```
<div id="bigWrap" style="background: #000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;
    height: 100%;">
    <div id="leftPage" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; float: left;
        text-align: center; position: relative;">
        <img id="imgDis" src="@Url.Content("~/" + Model.Path)" alt="@Model.MediaId" 
        style=" max-width: 90%;
                max-height: 90%;  "  />
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 1%; right: 0px;">
            <input id="closeImage" type="image" src="btnClose.png"
                onclick="$('#bigWrap').remove(); $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');" />
        </div>     
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 45%; right: 0px;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Next", "Images", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "nextImage" }))
            {    
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.MediaId);
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Path);
                <input id="btnNext" type="image" src="btnNext.png" />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user click on `next` button I call:

```
$(function () {
    $('#nextImage').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: "m_id=" + $('#imgDis').attr('alt'),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                $('#bigWrap').empty();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#bigWrap').prepend(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Next ActionMethod returns the same `Show` view just with new model (image):

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Next(int m_id)
    ...

return View("Show", model);
```

Now, the issues I have with this approach is:

1. When user click on thumb image is displayed but URL stays: http://localhost:xxxx/Images
2. When click on next button URL is still the same.
3. This only works when I am in Images/Index. If I
   open the image from some other view

With same function (from jquery call Show action) Url changes like http://localhost:xxxx/Images/Show?imgId=47, next button still changes nothing and when I close displayed view I got empty page in browser.

So what I made here obviously works when user watch images from index page and if user is not interested in url. But I want to change this but I am stuck here. So any idea what to do, what to fix or change everything is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: why not use a jQuery plugin that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. Why should you invent the wheel again? There are plenty of good plugins out there. My favorite is of course [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox). It has a nice UI ... check [these demos](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/). I would dare to say, it's the most downloaded lightbox/modal box out there.

There are also good examples of different scenarios, like [loading images from AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848492/1055987), [change the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743651/1055987), etc.

Comment: If I want to use FancyBox is there any way I can customize it like for example to add div on the right side of the image and load comments in that div?

Comment: so, did I get the bounty?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```
http://www.aspphotogallery.net/mvcphotogallery/Demo
```

or this one for serverside processing http://imageresizing.net/

Cheers
Parminder

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with starting from scratch, I would recommend using a jQuery plugin... take a look a the link below for a bunch of different plugins that are doing exactly what you want to do:

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/

Comment: I first was think to use lightbox (as I saw many other big sites use it) but I didn't succeeded to find any good resource to learn how to customize it to look like flickr ui for example. That's why I started to build from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the mentioned problems:

1,2 - Of course the url doesn't change, since you are using AJAX, and if you get something through AJAX the browser's URL doesn't change automatically, you have to change it after a successfull ajax call

3 - You should provide more information on how do you exactly call your Show action. It seems you are getting the result you describe because you are making a new http get request to your show action (and as expected the browser gets only the result of the show action), so its no wonder that after closing the image you see an empty page, because there is nothing else on the page

Even if you will be able to overcome these problems. I feel that you should really consider using an existing solution (either be it a jQuery plugin or a nuget package) for this problem as others suggested.

Comment: Actually you can change the URL without a reload as long as you're only changing the hash fragment of the URL. mypage.com/gallery.aspx can be changed to mypage.com/gallery.aspx#/photo/3617/beach_vacation/ this is very common in AJAX heavy applications and is how FB and G+ run their photo systems. It allows you to not only change the url for ajax loaded pages, but causes most browsers to store a history object for those pages which enables the forward/back navigation in the browser to work correctly by changing the hash tag which triggers JS code which loads the correct ajax content.