# FancyBox get href for images via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

Here is my problem.

I use FancyBox for showing images, which getting via AJAX.
There isn't exist images on page when page is loaded, only links with attributes with names of galleries.

So, when I click on one of these links handled this code:

```
    $(".fancybox-manual-c").live('click',function() {
            $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {'gal' : $(this).attr('rel')},
                    url : 'http://polygon.goracio.com.ua/gallery/getfiles.php',
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    complete: function(data) {
                            var dataX = data.responseText;
                            console.log(data.responseText);
                            var img = [
                                    {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30711.jpg'},
                                    {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-27082.jpg'},
                                    {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30988.jpg'},
                                    {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30858.jpg'},
                                    {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-23424.jpg'},];
                            var opts = {
                                    prevEffect : 'none',
                                    nextEffect : 'none',
                                    helpers : {
                                            thumbs : {
                                                    width: 75,
                                                    height: 50
                                            }
                                    }
                            };
                            $.fancybox(img, opts);
                        }
            });
    });
```

This solution works fine. But when I use

```
    var img = [dataX];
```

instead of

```
            var img = [
                {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30711.jpg'},
                {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-27082.jpg'},
                {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30988.jpg'},
                {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30858.jpg'},
                {href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-23424.jpg'},];
```

I'm get Pop-up window with responce text.

[Demo](http://polygon.goracio.com.ua/gallery/)

What i'm doing wrong?

- fancyBox - jQuery Plugin
- version: 2.0.5 (21/02/2012)
- jQuery 1.7 - latest

code of 'getfile.php'

```
function directoryToArray($directory, $recursive = true) {
    $array_items = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (is_dir($directory. "/" . $file)) {
                    if($recursive) {
                        $array_items = array_merge($array_items, directoryToArray($directory. "/" . $file, $recursive));
                    }
                    $directory = str_replace('./galleries/', '', $directory);
                    $file = $directory . "/" . $file;
                    $array_items[]= preg_replace("/\/\//si", "/", $file);
                } else {
                    $directory = str_replace('./galleries/', '', $directory);
                    $file = $directory . "/" . $file;
                    $array_items[] = preg_replace("/\/\//si", "/", $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $array_items;
}
header("Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
$arrays = directoryToArray( "./galleries/".$_POST['gal']);
foreach($arrays as $array){
    echo "{href:'/gallery/galleries/$array'}, \n";
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
        $(".fancybox-manual-ajax").live('click',function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : {'gal' : $(this).attr('rel')},
                url : 'http://polygon.goracio.com.ua/gallery/getfiles.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                complete: function(data) {
                    var dataX = data.responseText;
                    var dataXsplit = dataX.split(',');
                    var dataXarrayObj = new Array(), i;
                    for(i in dataXsplit){
                        if(dataXsplit[i].length){ //remove last empty element after .split()
                            dataXarrayObj[i] = $.parseJSON(dataXsplit[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    var opts = {
                        prevEffect : 'none',
                        nextEffect : 'none',
                        helpers : {
                            thumbs : {
                                width: 75,
                                height: 50
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    $.fancybox(dataXarrayObj, opts);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are not doing anything wrong but there are many factors to consider in this scenario

First, from your ajax call you get:

```
var dataX = data.responseText;
```

and the `responseText` property [gets the response data as a string](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp), so fancybox displays such *string* instead of the *array* of images.

What you have to do as a workaround is to convert such *string* into a javascript *object* so fancybox can parse it. There are different ways to do it. One is using the `eval()` function, but there can be security issues so this method is not recommended.

Since you are using jQuery, your safest way to do it is to use [jQuery.parseJSON( json )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), however you have to be sure that you will be converting a well-formed JSON string.

In your case, your "getfile.php" file seems to be rendering this format

```
{href:'/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30711.jpg'},....
```

but a well-formed JSON string should look like:

```
{"href":"/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30711.jpg"},...
```

*notice the mandatory **double quotes***.

Once you are sure that `data.responseText` returns a *string* like:

```
data.responseText='{"href":"/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-30711.jpg"},{"href":"/gallery/galleries/gallery1/wallpapers_by_ellin-27082.jpg"}, etc ....'
var dataX = data.responseText;
```

then you can 1). split the *string*, 2). convert every separated element into a javascript *object* and 3). place it into an *array* of objects like:

```
var dataXsplit = dataX.split(',');
var dataXarrayObj = new Array(), i;
for(i in dataXsplit){
 dataXarrayObj[i] = jQuery.parseJSON(dataXsplit[i]);
}
```

after that, you can fire fancybox with the proper *array* of objects (check API methods in the [fancybox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)) either doing:

```
var img = dataXarrayObj;
$.fancybox(img, opts);
```

or simply

```
$.fancybox(dataXarrayObj, opts);
```

Notice that you don't need to enclose the *array* in `[]` brackets

Comment: BTW, as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. For older versions of jQuery the use of `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var dataXsplit = dataX.split(',');
var dataXarrayObj = new Array(), i;
for(i in dataXsplit){
 dataXarrayObj[i] = jQuery.parseJSON(dataXsplit[i]);
}
```

You can do:

```
var img = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
```

So all together it would be something like this:

```
Xhr.onload = function() {
    var img = JSON.parse(Xhr.responseText);
    $.fancybox(img, {
    padding: 0,

    openEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 150,

    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150,

    closeClick : true
    });
};
```