# Fancybox content size issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am trying to make the same user interface to preview image like on facebook.
I have one separate view that I display in fancybox.
It must be that I have made same error with max/min width/height. Basically as I see comment div should be 340px width always. And image div is resizable based on image size. In images bellow I use wider image to better show problem.
I load it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'autoSize': true,
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'closeBtn': false,
            'type': 'ajax',
            'padding': 0, 
            'margin': 0,                        
            'minWidth': 500,
            'fitToView': true
        });
    });
```

It load view fine.
That inner view code is:

```
<div style="height: 610px; width: 1100px;">
    <div style="float: left; max-width: 510px;">
        <img style="max-height: 100%;" src="http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393726_2631619232954_1329592446_32973068_1109612286_n.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 340px; height: 100%; background: #ff0000;">
        <h3>
            Description</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I get now:
[image]
And this is what I am trying to get:
[image]

**UPDATE**
Issue with smaller image based on @S.Visser answer.
[image]

Comment: Possibly a CSS issue? try adding display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; to the container div that houses the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I use a table hack to center the image. The max width and height are there to make sure the image dont size to big.

#### html

```
<div id="popup-container">

    <div class="image">
          <img src="http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393726_2631619232954_1329592446_32973068_1109612286_n.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="description">
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

#### css

```
#popup-container {
    height: 610px;
    width: 1100px;
    display: table;
}

#popup-container .image {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #000;
}

#popup-container .image img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 760px;
}

#popup-container .description {
    width: 340px;   
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 610px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both; 
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I added your code and it's fine except when images are smaller. I added image to the question for smaller image. I was try to put min width/height 610/540 to #popup-container but it doesn't work. Can you help me just for this case...

Answer (score 3):

That may be a bit of work to customize, but you may consider my "*a la*" facebook way (using fancybox v2.x):

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html

BTW, you included API options of fancybox v1.3.x and v2.x in your script. Fancybox options in v2.x are new and not compatible with older versions.

Comment: ... and I have the impression that I already suggested that to you and you liked the idea: why you don't get the code from my sample?

Comment: What options are from 1.3?
Yes I accepted your answer before :) But here I am trying to change something I am in learning phase so I am changing things... @S.Visser answer fix it.

Comment: option for v1.3.x here http://fancybox.net/api and options for v2.x here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Is there any description about your example "ALfacebook" like how to use it with database or something like that? As I see now images urls ans side content must be loaded on the page but I work with thousands images and much more comments...

Comment: That is a separated issue. Of course you can populate your html page via ajax (links and descriptions) and then use the "ala" facebookk script. some example http://stackoverflow.com/a/9848492/1055987 ... but also it depends on how good you are at ajax.

Comment: I was thinking to make ajax call when I click on next button, can I write custom handler for next in this script. I have tried something but doesn't work...},
                next: function() { alert('test'); },
                nextEffect: 'fade',...