# Fancybox: problems with opacity

Tags: jquery, fancybox

am I right that the following syntax/code doesn't work (anymore)?

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.9,
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#f00' 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/3375/

... but only this?

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background-color' : 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .9)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/3374/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the format `rgba(255, 0, 0, .9)` then the css property should be `background`, not `background-color` as in your example code above. Then your script should look like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .9)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

... see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MjyWX/1/)** (I set a lower opacity value to make it more obvious)

Bear in mind that if you don't set any `background` property, fancybox will use a semitransparent **.png** image as background (fancybox_sprite.png). If you set the `background-color` property (as in your examples above), the *png* sprite still will be used and may affect the opacity effect you are looking for.

It seems like the `opacity` API option for the `overlay` was removed since version 2.1.x (last used was v2.0.6)