# Overlay not working fancybox v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'd like to change the overlay and opacity of a fancy box in the code below. I tried to add these lines based on JFK's suggestions but unfortunately it is not working:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

just after the opening script tag but without success. Any thoughts? Thanks

My full code now:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
});

function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#various1').trigger('click'); },2000);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1 });
    $('#various1').fancybox();

});
</script>
```

Within body tags:

```
<div id="various1" style="display:none;">
<h2>Welcome to our website!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740443/how-can-i-change-the-overlay-color-in-fancybox-v2

Comment: What selector are you actually using to fire fancybox : `.fancybox` or `various1`? because whatever it is, you have to apply your options to the script that binds fancybox to that selector. BTW, fancybox v2.x API options are new and not compatible with previous versions ... overlayOpacity is an option for v1.3.4. Check the docs for the right options you should be using http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: @Edward : unfortunately that post is outdated and valid for v2.0.x but not for v2.1.x .... se my answer for the new supported format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fancybox v2.x options are new and not compatible with previous versions ... for instance `overlayOpacity` and `overlayColor` are options for fancybox v1.3.4 and won't work with version 2.

Check [fancybox v2.x documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the right options you should be using.

To change color and opacity in fancybox 2, you should use this format (v2.1.4 as today) :

```
$("#various1").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

...where the last of the 4 numbers is the selected `opacity` (**EDIT** : the code above matches the OP's selector)

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cZxUp/)**

**IMPORTANT** : IE[6/7/8] doesn't support `rgba` .... check [this article](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks JFK. I have updated the code of my question based on your answer but unfortunately it is now working. Is the code placed at the wrong place? (I'm still having difficulties to identify what goes where with js) Thanks

Comment: @Greg : yes, it is the wrong place.... it should be as an option of `$('#various1').fancybox();`. If you don't have any link `<a>` with a `class="fancybox"` then you don't need this `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` script at all

Comment: @Greg : see my edited answer. Just remember that IDs should be **unique** so only one element can have that ID within the same document. If you want to apply the code to several elements, then use classes instead.

Comment: Actually I think that I spoke too fast... Doesn't seem to be working in my case. Could you have a look at http://goo.gl/rMIYJ pls ? (this is based on your latest code)? What I'm trying to achieve is to have some kind of opacity/background overlay applied to the whole page (except the fancybox) Many thanks

Comment: @Greg : you have two `$("#various1").fancybox()` scripts; the first one has the `helpers` option (as in my code) but the second, without it, overrides the first. You need to add the `helpers` option to the second (the one just after the `$.cookie()` script) and remove the first one on top.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your code in

```
$(function(){
//your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#fancybox-overlay {
  width: 100%;
}
```