# Overlay and fancybox 2 - doesn't show

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I try to get the overlay of Fancyboxe to display but no way.
I try to setup a helper like this but nothing work.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : { 
       overlay: {
        opacity: 0.8, // or the opacity you want 
        css: {'background-color': '#ff0000'}
       } // overlay 
      } // helpers
    }); // fancybox
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code is correct, as can be seen here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLhdP/) so be sure you have included jQuery, `jquery.fancybox.js` and `jquery.fancybox.css` on your page. Your code needs to be wrapped in `$(document).ready( function () { ... } );` also

Comment: Still not able to get this work. I have include jquery.fancybox.js and jquery.fancybox.css

Comment: hmm. and you've included jquery, and wrapped your function in a standard `$(document).ready` handler ?

Comment: what you mean about this : $(document).ready handler ?

Comment: ok, I'll move this to an answer for typing ease

Comment: Do you have any fiddle or webpage url to see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a function which tells the web page to run some code when the document is finished loading.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    'background-color' : '#ff0000'
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It's not working at all like this. No fancybox open but the image in a new tab of the browser.

Comment: ok, if you could create a jsfiddle with your markup and js, troubleshooting should be easier. offhand I'd say that if your link tags are triggering, you've forgotten to add the class `fancybox` to them.

Comment: how can i give you the code to make a jsfiddle ? (with adding the Fancybox class to the link nothing happend)

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net , add your html where it says html, css where it says css, and js where it says javascript. Or just look at the jsfiddle I linked, in the comments above and modify it. Click on `fork` or `update` when you are done, and copy/paste the link here

Comment: I found the problem i had a conflict with a cusom javascript code for googlemap API. Thanks everybody

Comment: @DomDay This code was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9743651/1055987 but it's one year old therefore obsolete (was for v2.0.x). Actually your own fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xLhdP/ works but notice that even the fancybox image has opacity 0.8. For the latest version use http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#fancybox-overlay {
  width: 100%;
}
```